# Add gif animation under UITabBar item

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 5 tabs.

I have a `GIF` file I want to place under each tab.

I'm using a [3rd party API (`UIImage` extension) called `SwiftGif`](https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGif) for using the gif so the question can be asked like that too:

"How can I place a `UIImage` as the background of my `UITabBar`"

But I wanted to be more specific to help you understand better.

Comment: When you say under the tab, do you mean right under the UITabBarItems? e.g. a Settings tab button with a gif under the title "Settings"

Comment: @tech4242 No, I mean to add a view between the Bar to the Tab in the TabBar. Understand?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure. This has to be more straightforward: are you just trying to add the UIImage gif from that github source to your UIViewController i.e. one of your tab pages? Because when you say **under** the UITabBar it kind of means under the bar itself.. maybe post a screenshot/mockup?

Comment: @tech4242 Well, I mean below, not under. To put it below to tab, between the tab to the bar

Comment: Can you provide us with a very basic mockup? I am a bit lost tbh because I think we mean different things when we say bar and tab :)

Comment: @tech4242 UITabBar. I should be `The TabBar's background image -> my gif UIImage -> The UITabBarItem`

Comment: I get it know! You want to have the gif between the background of the tab bar and the UITabBarItems i.e. a gif background for your tab bar. Right?

Comment: @tech4242 Yeah! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to change the background of your tabBar `self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage.gifWithName("yourGifName"))` Keep in my mind that this syntax is from Swift 3 - if you are using Swift 2, you might have to change it a bit

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4 :**
 a class for your tabbar then set images like that:

```
import UIKit
import SwiftGifOrigin  ///to install that pod:  https://github.com/bahlo/SwiftGifCreate 

class TabbarVC: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let myTabBarItem1 = (self.tabBar.items?[0])! as UITabBarItem
        myTabBarItem1.image = UIImage(named: "your unselected image")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage.gif(asset: "your gif")?.withRenderingMode(UIImage.RenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)
        myTabBarItem1.title = ""
        myTabBarItem1.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 6, left: 0, bottom: -6, right: 0)

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution work for me, just set gif for selected image in Tabbar class.

```
 import UIKit

class TabbarVC: UITabBarController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Set Selected image for all items, I'm doing only for item 1
    let myTabBarItem1 = (self.tabBar.items?[0])! as UITabBarItem
    myTabBarItem1.selectedImage = UIImage.gifImageWithName("image name")

  }

}
```

Here is the extension for loading `Gif` from `URL/Bundle/Name`.

```
extension UIImage {

  public class func gifImageWithData(_ data: Data) -> UIImage? {
      guard let source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData(data as CFData, nil) else {
          print("image doesn't exist")
          return nil
      }
      return UIImage.animatedImageWithSource(source)
  }

  public class func gifImageWithURL(_ gifUrl:String) -> UIImage? {
      guard let bundleURL:URL = URL(string: gifUrl)
          else {
              print("image named \"\(gifUrl)\" doesn't exist")
              return nil
      }
      guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
          print("image named \"\(gifUrl)\" into NSData")
          return nil
      }
      return gifImageWithData(imageData)
  }

  public class func gifImageWithName(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
      guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main
        .url(forResource: name, withExtension: "gif") else {
              print("SwiftGif: This image named \"\(name)\" does not exist")
              return nil
      }
      guard let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: bundleURL) else {
          print("SwiftGif: Cannot turn image named \"\(name)\" into NSData")
          return nil
      }

      return gifImageWithData(imageData)
  }
```